# Can rechargeable batteries with different mA values be used in the same device with good/normal results?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, battery-operated

If I use the two AA batteries (shown below) in a digital camera (where two are needed) will I experience any odd behavior due to the difference in mAh, such as:

1. camera not working properly?
2. battery power being dissipated more quickly?

Can you think of any other adverse issues that I might experience?

Also, is mAh (milliAmpere hours)?
What is the h denoting?

[image: energizer AA batteries]

Comment: When the smaller one runs flat, the larger one will attempt to charge it backwards, destroying it. So if you do this, stop using the camera and change batteries as soon as power seems to be getting low.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest answer is that the camera will perform as if you used 2 1400mAh cells.

First, we'll start with the h (hours).  The mAh rating suggests the cell can produce that much current for an hour.  Being a Marketing number, you can read this as, "Will never perform better than...".  In real life, you can get near this performance at lower currents, but at high currents the run time diminishes significantly.

Assuming the two cells are operated in series, the current through them must be the same (basic electronic principle).  If we assume the numbers are accurate, and that the camera consumes 1.4A (it doesn't), then the 1400 cell goes dead in an hour, while the 2300 could have gone (2300/1400)*1hr= 1.6 hours, only, everything stops around the time the first cell goes dead.

When the cells go dead, the camera should shut off, but since the second cell is still going strong, it may run for a little extra time.  During that time, the smaller cell will continue to be discharged (the larger cell is now doing all the work). That first cell may go all the way to zero volts, and the start charging backwards.  This is where your "adverse issues" occur.

In Primary cells (the non-rechargeable ones) in particular, the normal chemical reactions eat away at the case, but since you take the cell out before it's completely dead, the integrity is maintained.  Discharge it fully, though, and the cell beings to leak, damaging your equipment. If you take it  out immediately, you'll be ok, but leave it in there and you risk damage.

For rechargeable cells, running them down to nothing (or reversing them) will ruin them, and they may not recharge or run very long after that.  Here the damage is mostly financial (although rechargeable cells can leak as well).

Comment: Great, well-written, thorough answer.  The adverse issues you describe are what I had thought might happen and was one of the reasons I was curious.  It's also why I believe energizer should mark these two types of their AA batteries differently.  The 2300mAh with a red asterisk or something to denote it is different.

Answer (score 2):

If the two batteries are in series to produce 2.4V, then it could be bad.  The cell with a lower capacity will end up discharged first, while the other still has a good charge.

The battery that is still charged will then force a current through the flat battery, charging it *the wrong way*.  This can permanently damage the flat battery.

If you must do this, turn the camera off at the first sign of a low battery warning, and you may get away with it.

Comment: Your answer is correct. It's worth pointing out that even with matched batteries one may go flat before the other giving the same problem. Your last paragraph is the solution.

Comment: "This can permanently damage the flat battery."  I believe we've seen in the past this where the kids have mixed these batteries and then one of the batteries will no longer take a charge. Since these are rechargeable and they are not marked very clearly I know we've put them in the charger together too. Would that cause these kinds of issues too?  Could the charger kill the smaller mAh battery?

Comment: @raddevus That will depend on the charger.  Some charge each cell individually, some don't.

Answer (score 1):

The h is for hours as you point out.

If the capacity of the new batteries is lower than the original then the run-time will be lower, if larger then the run-time will be increased proportionally.

Comment: Mike - you may have missed the point of the question. The photo shows two identical looking cells but one is 1400 mAh and the other is 2000.

Comment: So, which of those two is the original? I assumed neither was as I answered - if you know for sure I would like to know how.... and the change in run time is still relevant...

Comment: He's mixing the batteries - one of each.